# How should I tweet about things happening on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, popularity, sharing

When I want to tweet about something happening on Stack Overflow, which hashtag or mentions should I be using?

Obviously, there's [`@StackExchange`](https://twitter.com/StackExchange) but it seems to be related to the entire network rather than just the site.

There's [`@StackCareers`](https://twitter.com/StackCareers) but that's just for the careers site.

There's something called [`@StackOverflowR`](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowR) but that's clearly an unofficial account and it only targets a single category.

I can see that [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) has an account, [`@StackProgrammer`](https://twitter.com/stackprogrammer). So does [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) ([`@StackCodeReview`](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview)). Is there a similar account for Stack Overflow?

Should I just use the hashtag `#StackOverflow` or use it in combination with `@StackExchange`?

Is there any official or commonly accepted line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this tweet by StackExchange](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/623924360273903617), starting today, there is going to be an [official Stack Overflow Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow)

`@StackOverflow` and `#StackOverflow` should be applicable

Comment: DAMNIT.  Was sure I'd get the accept on this one.  :P

Comment: @Jaydles haha, sorry, I just happened to be lurking on Twitter as well :)